Should Redis check if a key exists before getting the value?
I'm working on a legacy project, and the Redis Cache implementation will always check if a value exists before trying to get it or delete it.
For example:
...
    public function get($id): mixed
    {
        try {
            if ($this->connection->exists($id)) {
                return $this->connection->get($id);
            }
        } catch (PredisException $predisException) {
            ...
        }

        return null;
    }
...

It seems like this is overkill. I've looked online, but I can't seem to find this pattern anywhere. Is it correct that this is not necessary and hampers performance?
I have not tried to change anything yet, because this is in a pretty central part of our project.

Yes, this is an overkill. It can (and should) simply be changed to:
...
    public function get($id): mixed
    {
        try {
            return $this->connection->get($id);
        } catch (PredisException $predisException) {
            ...
        }
    }
...

Depending on what the catch block is doing, returning null from outside may not be necessary anymore.

Good to hear, thanks for your reply!
